# Variable Scope not working like I thought- Not able to access variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable in on load that I wish to access in another script. 
I wanted the variable runningSlider in onload to be global so that my button function could see it. It doesn't seem to be able to see it, as I get the error messsage: Cannot read property stop of null.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#c1').nivoSlider({ effect: 'fade' });
    runningSlider = 1; 
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#slideButtons button').click(function(){        
    var newID = $(this).attr("id");
    alert (newID);
    alert ('test of variable ' + runningSlider);
    $('#c' + runningSlider).data('nivoslider').stop();     
    $('#c' + newID).data('nivoslider').start();
    var runningSlider = newID;
});
</script>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: is runningSlider initialized as var in the first script?

Comment: You have a syntax error; missing `})` in the first `<script>` block

Comment: @depperm No it is not initialized as var in the first script. I thought that I wasn't supposed to use var so that it would be a global variable.

Comment: @Phil  = I fixed that in my post. Thank you. It was actually already in my code. Just sloppy copying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`runningSlider` in your `onload` handler is an implicit global variable because there is no `var` declaration within scope for it.  If you are not running in strict mode, then assigning to an undeclared variable will automatically create a global by that name (this is generally considered a bad practice).

`runningSlider` in your click handler is a local variable only available inside that function.  When a variable is declared with `var` within a function, then the variable becomes a local variable, available only within the scope of that function.  If you use `var` to declare a variable of the same name as a global, then the local variable "hides" or "overrides" the global name and any references to that variable name within the scope will access the local variable, not the global variable.

As you've written it, the two are completely separate variables.

If you want to share a single global, then the way to do that is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// declare global
var runningSlider;
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#c1').nivoSlider({ effect: 'fade' });
    // set global
    runningSlider = 1; 
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#slideButtons button').click(function(){        
    var newID = $(this).attr("id");
    alert (newID);
    alert ('test of variable ' + runningSlider);
    $('#c' + runningSlider).data('nivoslider').stop();     
    $('#c' + newID).data('nivoslider').start();
    // update global
    runningSlider = newID;
});
</script>
```

FYI, you were also missing a `});` to close your load handler.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I took out the var in the click and Yes this worked.  But if this is bad code, is there a better way to do this? Will it cause me unforeseen problems? This is just being used in a 5 page website with only me taking care of it.

Comment: I don't know the whole context, but it may be OK to use the global, just make sure you declare it in the global scope like my code shows rather than using an implicit global that isn't actively declared.

Comment: ah, Now I get it: I was thinking that only one function between each script but that is not the case at all I see. I bit off more than I can chew comfortably by taking on our choirs website  I am stuffing in as much as I can though :) I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @geddeca - since it looks like you're fairly new here at StackOverflow, are you aware that if you get your question answered, you can select a best answer by clicking the green checkmark to the left of that answer.  This will earn both you and the answered some reputation points and will indicate to the community that you're question has been answered.

Comment: thank you for pointing that out. I checked it and hit the up arrow. I am also wondering if there is some way  to mark text as code in a comment. not just in my original post.

Comment: @geddeca - you can use the backwards apostrophe before and after some code to format it as code like this `var foo = 1;`.  But, a word of warning, this only works well in a comment for a short piece of code that is one line or less.  Anything else, you can edit your question or answer to add it there and then refer to it in a comment.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for more formatting info.